# Ocaml-What is the most efficient way to calculate hash values for all substrings in a string?

Tags: string, hash, ocaml

What is the most efficient way to obtain hash values for all substrings in a string. I tried to use:

```
let str1 = "AHTG...";;(*1000000 chars*)
let tam = 2;;
for i = 0 to String.length str1 - tam do
  let st = String.sub str1 i tam in
  Hashtbl.add hash_table (Hashtbl.hash st) i;
done;
```

to calculate all substrings with size =2 (AC,CH,TA,...) of a string with size = 1000000 and add values to hash_table but it takes a lot of time to finish the process,i think. I was wondering if there is any process more efficient and faster than the one presented above?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? How does it differ from "faster"?

Comment: it's the same scene

Comment: Aren't you actually looking for the trie data structure?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Also, in general it is a good idea to describe the problem that you're trying to solve. To avoid the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem that is very common on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are a lot of substrings of a string, around n^2/2 of them I would say. This is a big number when n = 1e6. If your hash function is a black box with no known arithmetic properties, and your string also has no known extra properties, you basically have to do O(n^2) calls to your hash function, which will take a long time.

If your hash function has interesting arithmetic properties, like say hash(a ^ b) = hash(a) + hash(b) mod K, you might be able to do a little better. On the other hand, properties like this probably make a weaker hash.

As an immediate improvement, you might consider a hash function that works directly on a substring. That will save you a lot of calls to String.sub and the associated consing and GC. (Probably this won't help a lot as OCaml has a really good GC for short-lived values.)